# After installing pyuic4 I am getting bash: pyuic4: command not found

Tags: pyqt4

Pyuic4 I have already installed on my CentOS 7. I was trying to do `pyuic4 –x demo.ui –o demo.py`. This command it was producing error

```
bash: pyuic4: command not found...
```

(Note: I have installed Qt4 and Qt4 Designer)

Comment: sorry i didnot get you

Comment: Sorry. It should have been the edit note. Misplaced by a userscript.

Comment: @GunaSekaranJ. You probably need to install some kind of extra `dev` or `tools` package for pyqt4.